# Need helping know name of this anime movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

So I watched this anime movie a few years (when DVDs were still a thing but not eh 90s) back.  I think it was English dubbed not quite sure.  But it starts with a boy and his family traveling I think.  Then they get ambushed by like thugs or then the whole family gets killed.  The boy had a sister. But just as the boy was about to get killed this badass swordsman saves him and kills all the thugs.

The majority of the movie's plot was about the swordsman's past.  About when he was I wouldn’t say young but not that grown either.  I remember he gets married to some girl because the girl's village or wherever she lived got attacked.  The dad made a last minute decision to have them two get married and run away and stuff I guess.

And I also remember that in the end of the movie the wife gets killed by a bunch of people attacking them.  Because in the morning the swordsman went outside and when he was coming back had to fight a bunch of people.  It was snowing outside during that time I think.  The wife gets caught between him and this last guy and ends up dying.

It is not sword and the stranger but idk the name of the movie either can someone tell me what it is please.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the Rurouni Kenshin ("Samurai X" elsewhere) OVA "Trust & Betrayal"; the protagonist is traveling with a group attacked by bandits when young, does the usual training thing under said badass. There is no formal marriage, the two are hiding out as a doctor and wife due to the town being too hot for the swordsman to stay in.